# GNU Screen: Creating new window with title specified

Tags: gnu-screen

Is there a way of creating new window in GNU screen with title specified while creating the window itself.

I know that I can create a new window and then set the title using `^A A` but is there a way of mentioning tilte while creating the window itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

```
^A : screen -t title command
```

`^A:` brings up the screen prompt, and the rest of the line is a command to create a window with title "title" running command "command".

Below is the relevant documentation for the screen subcommand from the `screen(1)` manpage.

```
   screen [-opts] [n] [cmd [args]|//group]

   Establish  a  new  window.  The flow-control options (-f, -fn and -fa),
   title (a.k.a.) option (-t), login options (-l and -ln) , terminal  type
   option  (-T <term>), the all-capability-flag (-a) and scrollback option
   (-h <num>) may be specified with each command.  The option  (-M)  turns
   monitoring on for this window.  The option (-L) turns output logging on
   for this window.  If an optional number n in the range  0..MAXWIN-1  is
   given, the window number n is assigned to the newly created window (or,
   if this number is already in-use, the next  available  number).   If  a
   command is specified after "screen", this command (with the given argu‐
   ments) is started in the window; otherwise, a  shell  is  created.   If
   //group  is supplied, a container-type window is created in which other
   windows may be created inside it.

   Thus, if your ".screenrc" contains the lines

               # example for .screenrc:
               screen 1
               screen -fn -t foobar -L 2 telnet foobar

   screen creates a shell window (in window #1) and a window with a TELNET
   connection  to the machine foobar (with no flow-control using the title
   "foobar" in window #2) and will write a logfile ("screenlog.2") of  the
   telnet session.  Note, that unlike previous versions of screen no addi‐
   tional default window is created when "screen" commands are included in
   your  ".screenrc"  file.  When  the initialization is completed, screen
   switches to the last window specified in your  .screenrc  file  or,  if
   none, opens a default window #0.
   Screen  has built in some functionality of "cu" and "telnet".  See also
   chapter "WINDOW TYPES".
```